# Resolve shortened url using Rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am searching for a gem to resolve a shortened url and produce actual url.
Is there any gem doing this?

I searched web, but cannot able to find a useful tool for this.

Please let me know if you have already came across such tool (or gem in Rails)

thanks,
Balan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the URL shortening service. That said, this will work with any service using a 301 status code and the `Location` header:

```
require 'net/http'

def get_long_url(short_url)
  uri = URI.parse(short_url)
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host)
  response = http.get(uri.path)
  response.fetch('location')
end

get_long_url("http://bit.ly/LmvF") #=> http://google.com
```

Note though you will probably want to add some error checking and timeout handling on top of this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a gem to do this.

include `gem "longurl", "~> 0.1.6"` in your gem file, and after running `bundle install`

You can use the below code to get the actual url

> long_url = LongURL.expand(short_url)

Ref : [Long Url](http://rubygems.org/gems/longurl)